# Add more YouTubeThumbnailView at the END of the list Android

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, youtube-api, adapter

I am developing an app which shows Grid view of youTubeThumbnailView , I want to load more youTubeThumbnailView when user reach at the end of the list.
Suppose I have 2 list of video, I want to load 1st list at the beginning and load the 2nd list if user goes the bottom of the list.

My Custom Adapter for showing Grid View

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context mContext;
private final String[] video_id;
YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
public CustomGrid(Context c,  String[] video_id) {
    mContext = c;
    this.video_id=video_id;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return video_id.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        youTubeThumbnailView= (YouTubeThumbnailView) grid.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY,new ThumbnailListener(mContext,video_id[position]));
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    return grid;
}
```

MainActivity class

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this,youtube_id);
    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I can detect if user scroll at the bottom using Abslistview.onscrolllistener. How can I add more youTubeThumbnailView to adapter and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() ???

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a public method to your adapter and call it with the new List.

```
public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;       
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Edit. 
For exactly your case:

```
 public void updateData(String[] video) {
            this.video_id= video;       
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

And then in the Fragment or Activity.

adapter.updateData(yourNewStringArray);

Comment: It is the original List that you use inside your adapter, for example here:

 @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mDataItems.get(position);
    }

Comment: The same List you set in the constructor of the adapter

Comment: Thanks for quick response . but I am still little confused . I do not make any List , like you suggest , should i make  youTubeThumbnailView List or what? I am really sorry, i am a beginner of android, that's why i can catch your answer .

Comment: public CustomGrid(Context c,  String[] video_id) {
    mContext = c;
    this.video_id=video_id;
}
String[] video_id could also be List<String>video

Comment: Thanks bro, It's worked. Can you help me little more, how to load grid view in asynctask? Because Log cat says, App is working too much on main thread. I will be highly great full if you give me a link.

Comment: No Problem. Forget about asynctask, use asynctaskLoader or okhttp with a callback, or  REST client,for example - Retrofit. Links for okhttp and retrofit - https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes, http://square.github.io/retrofit/

AsynctaskLoader example with Adapter - http://www.pinnsg.com/async-task-loader-populate-static-list-view/